# After one redirect all child route are active

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In one page of my Angular 15 app I have one router to display nested routes:

```js
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
```

Where my `app-sidebar` is:

```js
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let route of profileRoutes">
    <ion-button
      [routerLink]="route.path"
      routerLinkActive="active-item">
      {{ route.label }}
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And `profileRoutes` implements this interface:

```js
export interface ProfileRoute {
  path: string;
  label: string;
}
```

Here there is the configuration of my routes:

```js
const routes = [
  {
     path: 'profile',
     loadComponent: () =>
       import('./path-to-component').then(
         m => m.Component
       ),
     children: childrenRoutes,
  }
]
const childrenRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'route-1',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('path-to-component').then(
        m => m.Component
      ),
  },
  {
    path: 'route-2',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('path-to-component').then(
        m => m.Component
      ),
  },
  ...
]
```

**Behavior**

1. Click on the button `route-1` once and works as expected (redirect to `/profile/route-1`).
2. Afterwards, click on button `route-2` and the user doesn't get redirect, plus all button get the class `active-item` signaling that all routes are triggered as `active`.
3. If I right click and "Open in another tab", the route is triggered as expected and I can restart from action 1.

Furthermore, this warning is logged on action 2.

> The navigation to /profile/route-1 will instead go to /profile/route-2 in an upcoming version of Angular. `relativeTo` might need to be removed from the `UrlCreationOptions`

But I've never used `relativeTo` anywhere.

I tried to add a name at the secondary `ion-router-outlet` and adding the `outlet` property at the paths in `childrenRoutes` but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `routerLink` automatically set the `relativeTo` option to your current route, and you want it to be your parent route.
You could use `activatedRoute` to find your parent route and `relativeTo` it. Note that now you have to add `profile` to your path.

```js
<ion-button
    [routerLink]="['profile', route.path]"
    [relativeTo]="activatedRoute.parent"
    routerLinkActive="active-item">
    {{ route.label }}
</ion-button>
```

Comment: I tried this and it works fine until I navigate away from the parent then back then it stops working.

Comment: I tested that scenario and it works fine

Comment: What ionic/angular version did you use it on?

[redirectTo]="activatedRoute.parent"

this is not avialable?

  this.router.navigate(['verified-assets', path], {
                relativeTo: this.route.parent,
            });

Comment: It was a typo from my side, I meant to write `relativeTo` instead of `redirectTo`! Using `routerLink` you can't pass the `relativeTo` argument, you have to specify it separately. My answer proposed the "template version" of what you are doing using the router API

Comment: Yeah it doesnt work 

 this.router.navigate(['verified-assets', path], {
                relativeTo: this.route.parent,
            });


did you use nested ion-router-outlet or nested router-outlet

Comment: Yeah the question talks about a "secondary router", so I assumed it was using 2 nested `ion-router-outlet`s

Comment: Ended up ditching ion-router-outlet and it all works perfectly now. Thanks.